# How to insert records for custom metadata types for my test class?

Tags: apex

I have an apex class with a method where I gather a set of customerTypes from the metadata

```
private static Set<String> getCustomerTypes(){
        Set<String> customerTypes = new Set<String>();
        for(Customer__mdt meta : [SELECT Id,Customer__c FROM Customer__mdt]){
            customerTypes.add(meta.Customer__c);
        }
        return customerTypes;
    }

@AuraEnabled
    public static Detail__c getDetailsOnOpportunity(Id opportunityId){
        System.debug('details per Opp is ' + opportunityId);
        List<Opportunity> oppRecord = new List<Opportunity>();
        List<Detail__c> Detail = new List<Detail__c>();
        Set<String> customerTypes = getCustomerTypes();
        try {
            oppRecord = [Select Id,Account.CustomerType__c from Opportunity Where Id =: opportunityId];
            if(!oppRecord.isEmpty()){
                if(customerTypes.contains(oppRecord[0].Account.CustomerType__c)){
                    Detail = [Select
                                         Id,
                                         CompletionDate__c,
                                         Phone__c,
                                         Email__c
                                         From Detail__c
                                         Where Opportunity__c =:opportunityId LIMIT 1
                                        ];
                    if(!Detail.isEmpty()){
                        System.debug('details per Opp ' + Detail[0]);
                        return Detail[0];
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }    
                } else {
                    throw new CustomException(Label.Customer_Type_Invalid, Label.Customer_Type_Invalid, 0);
                }
            }
        } catch(CustomException be) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(
                JSON.serialize(be)
            );
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I am writing a test class for this method but I am struggling to create the test data for this method. Any pointers are appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot insert Custom Metadata in a unit test. You can *create* the instance in memory:

```
My_CMT__c myCMT = new My_CMT__c(... values ...);
```

but you can't insert them:

```
insert myCMT; // failure
```

and you can't call the Apex Metadata API to deploy them.

Instead, you have to use a dependency injection approach. Often, that takes the form of factoring out a query into a new class and replacing that class with a mock one.

Here, since you're only using values digested from Custom Metadata, I think you can streamline it a little. I'd define a property with getter and setter on this class in such a way that I can directly set its value in my test class:

```
@TestVisible
public static String customerTypes {
    get {
        if (customerTypes == null) {
            // Do a query and populate the values
        }

        return customerTypes;
    }
    private set;
}
```

Then, in your test class, you can directly call the setter to populate the value:

```
@isTest
public static void myTest() {
    MyClass.customerTypes = new Set<String>{'test', 'test', 'test'};

    // validate behavior
}
```

You'll need to separately write a test for the getter to ensure it performs a query, but you don't necessarily need to validate the results of the query since it'll be org-dependent.

Comment: This is immensely helpful. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for asking such a dumb question : But, after this MyClass.customerTypes = new Set<String>{'test', 'test', 'test'};  won't the value of MyClass.customerTypes be the original values but not test ?

Comment: @user3920709 Not a dumb question at all. The static variable will retain its value for the duration of the transaction. One test method is one transaction. When you set its value explicitly in the test method, the `if (customerTypes == null)` check in the getter method prevents the "real" query from running.

Comment: Then, in production, `customerTypes` isn't pre-set - it starts out `null`. That makes sure your query runs, but it runs only once per transaction. It's a lazy-loading pattern that also helps keep your code efficient.